# Unknown command-line option '--recompile-scripts'. After updating gradle to 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

With the update of Android Studio to 3.4 gradle was updated to 5.1.1. With this new version I tried to profile the build speed (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#profile) by executing the following command: `gradlew --profile --recompile-scripts --offline --rerun-tasks assemble<Flavor><Buildtype>`.
Sadly the option `'--recompile-scripts'` is not known anymore. Is there any replacement for this option?

Answer (score 3):

It has been removed by the Gradle team :https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1425
Try cleanBuildCache before build

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading the build.gradle from `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`(or any other version) may help you